# Error 404 on Network Admin and others

Tags: multisite, 404-error

I have a multisite fresh install in my domain. Subfolder setup.

Network Admin on the upper right menu has this link `http://example.com/wp-admin/network/` and returns a 404 error. Other links like 'Add New' have this problem too. I can manually visit `http://example.com/subfolder/wp-admin/network/` and works fine.

I'm not good with .htaccess but I think the problem is there; can you check this please:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) home/content/70/10156275/html/example.net/subfolder/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ home/content/70/10156275/html/example.com/subfolder/$1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Also, not sure if this helps but my `wp-config.php` has this code:

```
/* Multisite */
define( 'MULTISITE', true );
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true );
$base = '/';
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'example.com' );
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
```

I have been searching Google for 2 days now and can't fix this…
The problem is the subfolder is somewhat omitted in Network Admin and some few…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `.htaccess` rules are referencing a path *outside* of the document root, which is not allowed in .htaccess files.

Here is the complete working code for your `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) /subfolder/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ /subfolder/$1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

The code in your `wp-config.php` file is correct and therefore requires no change.